# SharePoint Online, intermittent 500 errors

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, error, internal-server-error

I'm seeing a lot of intermittent 500 errors in SharePoint Online CSOM code today. This code has been in place for a long time. The errors are happening at various parts of the code, doing different things, but usually, involve downloading or uploading a file.

I can't replicate anything in the UI, so I'm hesitant to open an O365 ticket.

Two questions -

1) Do you think this a throttling issue?

2) Have you had any luck opening help tickets when the issue can't be replicated through the SharePoint UI? Mine seems to be intermittent on top of that, which would make it even harder to document.

Answer (score 2):

Throttling only kicks in when it's extreme API abuse. Thousands or even Tens of Thousands of calls in a short time period. Are you uploading a ton of files? Is your code caught in a bad loop that's pounding the server with repeat requests? Check that first.

I've learned that SharePoint Online has a lot of "blips" in their up-time. I used to try to hit the site manually in Chrome when I saw 500's from API calls, and 99 times out of 100 the site itself was choking on something (network, server, etc.). Slow page loads. Random error pages. It's a symptom of something bigger than your puny scripts.

If the errors are intermittent (daily even) and not causing problems for end-users, I wouldn't worry about it. Downtime should be expected. If this is serious business and causing financial loss, review your code, then open the MS ticket, then consider putting this type of critical app into something else. ;)

Comment: I've opened a ticket, but not expecting much back.

Comment: Actually, it now seems there is a reported issue (SP196186)